# How to remove more than one commas yet keep at least one in a string?

Tags: javascript

I want to have only one comma after each number and remove excess commas which in between numbers:

For example of there is number

> 73663,,,,,,662633,6666777,,,,,,,56,7,,,77788,665,654446

After removing excessive commas I should have

> 73663,662633,6666777,56,7,77788,665,654446

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: does the string have a comma at the end? and would you like to remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\,+/g` along with `replace()`.

Here `\,+` will match one or more `,` and the trailing `g` will look for the match in the string globally.

The `replace()` will replace all the matching occurrences with single comma(`,`).

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var numStr = "73663,,,,,,662633,6666777,,,,,,,56,7,,,77788,665,654446";

numStr = numStr.replace(/\,+/g, ',');

console.log(numStr)
```

Answer (score 3):

use `\,+` which will check for one or more commas then replace it with a single comma at global scope:

```js
var str = '73663,,,,,,662633,6666777,,,,,,,56,7,,,77788,665,654446';
var res = str.replace(/\,+/g, ',');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look for comma and positive lookahead of more commas or end of string.

```js
var string = '63522,,,,,,,,,72626,,,,,,6336,,,62627,,,,,,,,,26363,2626,,,62662,';

console.log(string.replace(/,+(?=,|$)/g, ''));
```